# LINQ to SQL - Linq tries to insert column which doesn't exist

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I created a simple database schema in Visual Studio and deployed to SQL Server. Then I created Linq-to-SQL mappings by dragging all the tables onto my model from the server explorer.

After some time I decided to drop one column from the link table. I modified schema, removed database and deployed it again. I recreated my mappings by removing all entities from diagram and dragging all tables again.

The problem is, that when I try to insert new entity to that table (on which I dropped my column), Linq-to-SQL still tries to insert a value there and that triggers a SQL Exception, saying that `Szkola` column name is invalid. I double checked entity diagram - no sign of `Szkola` column there and IntelliSense also doesn't show that `Szkola` might exist. But after inspecting generated SQL (after calling `.SubmitChanges()`):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Uczen_Opiekun]([UczenPESEL], [OpiekunPESEL], [StopienPokrewienstwa], [Szkola])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3)
-- @p0: Input VarChar (Size = 8000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [10987654321]
-- @p1: Input VarChar (Size = 8000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [12345678910]
-- @p2: Input VarChar (Size = 8000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [ojciec]
-- @p3: Input VarChar (Size = 8000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [Null]
```

I cleaned solution couple of times, removed and recreated mappings and database several times and nothing helped. Why this is happening and how to solve this issue?

**EDIT 1:**

I followed **dasblinkenlight** instructions and looked into *.dbml file via text editor. I found several occurences of `Szkola` column in other tables since it's a validation table, but in `Uczen_Opiekun` link table (which causes problem) I didn't find any `Szkola` references...

```
<Table Name="dbo.Uczen_Opiekun" Member="Uczen_Opiekuns">
    <Type Name="Uczen_Opiekun">
      <Column Name="UczenPESEL" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(11) NOT NULL" IsPrimaryKey="true" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="OpiekunPESEL" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(11) NOT NULL" IsPrimaryKey="true" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="StopienPokrewienstwa" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(64)" CanBeNull="true" />
      <Association Name="Opiekun_Uczen_Opiekun" Member="Opiekun" ThisKey="OpiekunPESEL" OtherKey="PESEL" Type="Opiekun" IsForeignKey="true" />
      <Association Name="Uczen_Uczen_Opiekun" Member="Uczen" ThisKey="UczenPESEL" OtherKey="PESEL" Type="Uczen" IsForeignKey="true" />
    </Type>
  </Table>
```

### **Edit 2:**

Following suggestion from comments, I checked generated `Uczen_Opiekun` entity. There is no `Szkola` column, but still it's present in insert statement generated by Linq. Here is a short listing with fields generated from database schema.

```
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Uczen_Opiekun")]
    public partial class Uczen_Opiekun : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);          
        private string _UczenPESEL;         
        private string _OpiekunPESEL;           
        private string _StopienPokrewienstwa;           
        private EntityRef<Opiekun> _Opiekun;            
        private EntityRef<Uczen> _Uczen;
        (...)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no magic: `Szkola` must be somewhere in your dbml file. Open that file in a text editor (if you use Visual Studio, right-click and choose "Open With...", then "Text Editor"). Now search for `Szkola`, and remove it from the XML.

Comment: I edited my question with results of your advice. Unfortunately it didn't work since there was no `Szkola` reference in `Uczen_Opiekun` table mapping.

Comment: @jjczopek That is strange. Could you also take a look at the generated C# classes (under your dbml file) and check them for the signs of the `Szkola` field?

Comment: It's strange indeed and annoying as well. I inspected `Uczen_Opiekun` entity class in code, and didn't find any reference to my removed field.

Comment: @jjczopek This is really puzzling. Try this: find the constructor of the `Uczen_Opiekun` class, and set a breakpoint there. Now run your program, ans see if the breakpoint gets hit. At this point I suspect that you are seeing some sort of a build issue.